# Handling UIGestureRecognizer Swipe Left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to add a gesture recognizer using the following code.

However, the gesture is not getting recognized. Is there something else I have to do in order to make the view controller a delegate of the view--or something to that effect?

I have implemented the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol in the `.h` file

```
//in view did load
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
    rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [_myImage addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];


    //........towards left Gesture recogniser for swiping.....//
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
    leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [_myImage addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];

//new methods
- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Do moving
    NSLog(@"Right Swipe performed");//not appearing
}

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    // do moving
    NSLog(@"Left Swipe performed");//not appearing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1st you need

```
   _myImage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

then

```
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

  // Setting the swipe direction.
  [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
  [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

   // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
   [_myImage addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
   [_myImage addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

then call method like

```
 - (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

   if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
      {
         NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
      }
     if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
      {
        NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
     }
  }
```

i hope this will work..

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable user interaction of "_myImage" before adding gestures to image view as:
_myImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;